# Reading JSON file from S3 with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

First of all, I'm new to AWS so I apologize if the question is very simple or not explained properly.
I'm trying to read a JSON file stored in a S3 bucket with an AWS lambda function.
My main problem is that I am completely unable to extract the information from it.
This is my code:

**

```
import json
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    BUCKET = 'BUCKET'
    KEY = 'KEY.json'
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    result = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=KEY)
    # Read the object 
    text = result['Body'].read()#.decode('utf-8')
    #convert to string
    text_str = str(text)
    text_str = text_str.replace('\r\n', '')

    print(text_str)
```

**

If i use decode('utf-8'), I get: "errorMessage": "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 976: invalid start byte".
If i don't, i get the JSON file but like this:

'{\r\n  "id": 0,\r\n  "uid": "uid",\r\n  "name": "User",\r\n  "last": "Candidate"}'

I am stuck here, because the .replace doesn't work and I don't know how to use what i get and access to it as in a standard JSON.

Thank you in advance.

---

Update: looks like the main problem is that I have ASCii characters like 'á' in the JSON file. Now, I get something like this (I just show a part of the json):

'{"id": 0,"uid": "uid","name": "User","last": "Candidate"}'

I've tried ast.literal_eval to get rid of the '' and access the dictionary, and also json.dumps to try to avoid the problem with the ASCii characters, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your JSON file, '\r\n' is just the DOS line ending...I'll assume you created the file in a windows editor and save it.

Comment: Why not just do `json.loads(text_str)`?

Comment: @dmulter I get the same output, so still don't know how to work with it

Comment: This works fine for me in the REPL and outputs ` {'id': 0, 'uid': 'uid', 'name': 'User', 'last': 'Candidate'}`:

    >>> txt = '{\r\n "id": 0,\r\n "uid": "uid",\r\n "name": "User",\r\n "last": "Candidate"}'
    >>> import json
    >>> json.loads(txt)